# Registro de usuarios usando más de un formulario a la vez

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Estoy tratando de hacer el registro de usuarios para mi sitio usando dos formularios a la vez , y sale este error:

```
     AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Pilin\PycharmProjects\Perfiles\Otromas\views.py", line 10, in register
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 91, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 291, in __init__
    object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 82, in model_to_dict
    opts = instance._meta
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 216, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

forms.py

```
  from django import forms
     from Otromas.models import User, ProfesorProfile
     from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

    class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = {
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'password1',
                'password2',
                'is_estudiante',
                'is_profesor'
            }

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user


    class ProfesorForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ProfesorProfile
            fields = {
                'asignatura',
                'departamento'
            }
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Otromas.forms import RegistrationForm, ProfesorForm


# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        formP = ProfesorForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profesorprofile)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formP.save()
            redirect('admin')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        formP = ProfesorForm
        args = {'form': form, 'formP': formP}
        return render(request, 'regis.html', args)
```

Comment: puedes pegar el traceback completo del error?

Comment: actualice mi pregunta con el traceback

Answer (score 0):

moficando la views.py pude resolver el problema:

views.py

```
 def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        formP = ProfesorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            formP = ProfesorForm(request.POST, instance=user.profesorprofile)
            formP.full_clean()
            formP.save()

            redirect('/')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        formP = ProfesorForm
        args = {'form': form, 'formP': formP}
        return render(request, 'regis.html', args)
```